# Does this vector span $\mathbb{R}^{k}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals

Let $p_k(t)$ be a set of functions linearly independet of eachother, with $k>0$. Let $u$ be  any function. Both p, and u are continuous and integrable. Let

$\alpha_k=\int_{0}^{T} p_k(T-\tau)u(\tau))d\tau$, where T is a fixed number.

My question is: does the set of (infinite)vectors of the form $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_k )$ but with different u(t), span $\mathbb{R}^{k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to revised question.

Yes.  Consider the matrix $G=(g_{ij})$ of inner products $g_{ij}=\int_0^Tp_i(t)p_j(t)dt$.  Your hypotheses imply that $G$ is positive definite (for else if $a'G a = 0$ there would exist a linear relation $\sum_i a_i p_i = 0$ among your functions).  But positive definite matrices are non-singular, so for  any $\alpha\in \mathbb R^k$ there exists an $a$ for which $\alpha=Ga$.  Now consider the function $u(t)=\sum_i a_i p_i(T-t)$.  When you integrate this $u$ against your $p_i$ you recover $\alpha$.  So the set of $\alpha$ obtained this way is all of $\mathbb R^k$, and hence so is its span.

Comment: interesting, because in my control theory book (in swedish), they say that these $\alpha_k$ span R^k

Comment: Maybe you misstated the hypotheses.  Maybe that book talks about the collection of vectors you get as you vary $T$.  But the span of a single vector in $\mathbb R^k$ is either 0 or 1 dimensional.

Comment: And, if the function $u$ is identically 0, even if you look at the collection of $\alpha$ vectors you get as you vary $T$, the claim fails.

Comment: I mean that you can change u(t) however you want so that you get a collection of different $\alpha_k$ which u then form vectors of . Its all of these vectors that i want the span of.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to ask what you really mean to ask, then? What are you assuming about the $p$ functions?  Continuous?  Integrable?

Comment: Just did. Sorry